# Handlebar iterate Object of arrays

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am looking for iterating list of objects of arrays

Here is my sample object

```
var Categories =    {
      "communication": [
        {
          "id": "communication_001",
          "category": "communication",
          "lastModified": "4 Day ago"
        },
        {
          "id": "communication_002",
          "category": "communication",
          "lastModified": "1 Day ago"
        }
      ],
      "social": [
        {
          "id": "social_001",
          "category": "social",
          "lastModified": "2 Day ago"
        }
      ],
      "storage": [
        {
          "id": "storage_001",
          "category": "storage",
          "lastModified": "3 Day ago"
        }
      ]
    }
```

here I am compling with handlebar

```
 var render = Handlebars.compile(template)

render({ Categories : Categories  })
```

so what will be my template for compiling?

Suggest me the handlebar template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exactly know which key to iterate on, you could try something like the following:

```
<div>
 {{#each communication}}
  <div>{{id}}</div>
  <div>{{category}}</div>
  <div>{{lastModified}}</div>
 {{/each}}

 {{#each social}}
  <div>{{id}}</div>
  <div>{{category}}</div>
  <div>{{lastModified}}</div>
 {{/each}}

 {{#each category}}
  <div>{{id}}</div>
  <div>{{category}}</div>
  <div>{{lastModified}}</div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could try iterating with a double #each on ***this*** object, to access all the children and iterate over keys automatically:

```
<div>
 {{#each this}}
  {{#each this}}
   <div>{{id}}</div>
   <div>{{category}}</div>
   <div>{{lastModified}}</div>
  {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an object just like you can an array. You do not need to wrap the data in another object — simply refer to `this`.

```js
var categories = {
  "communication": [{
      "id": "communication_001",
      "category": "communication",
      "lastModified": "4 days ago"
    }, {
      "id": "communication_002",
      "category": "communication",
      "lastModified": "1 day ago"
    }
  ],
  "social": [{
    "id": "social_001",
    "category": "social",
    "lastModified": "2 days ago"
  }],
  "storage": [{
    "id": "storage_001",
    "category": "storage",
    "lastModified": "3 days ago"
  }]
};
var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
var render = Handlebars.compile(template);

document.getElementById('target-element').innerHTML = render(categories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="target-element"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <h1>Categories</h1>
 {{#each this}}
  <h2>{{@key}}</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each this}}
   <li><span>{{id}}</span> &mdash; <span>{{lastModified}}</span></li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
 {{/each}}
</script>
```